# Legend Text Spacing

Tags: reporting-services, charts

It seems as if the simple stuff is really giving me a work over in SSRS.

I have a legends and the text spacing is all weird.

I would like it to start at the top with no spaces in between.

[image]

I have checked the Legend settings, but can;t seem to pin point where to set this.

Thank you for your assistance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your report layout (in Design View) and perhaps the properties of your Legend? If I add a doughnut chart with a legend, I'm not able to get it to appear like your screenshot - do you have newlines or other non-printable characters in the values of the field used as the category group (i.e. the field which contains the `"IDLE"` and `"PRODUCTION"` values)?

Comment: I have even went as far as to Trim the data in my SQL query before presenting it on the report. My initial thought was exactly this, it must have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: As you suggest, `TRIM` functions usually only remove whitespace - I wonder if you have line feed and/or carriage return characters in there somewhere. Could you confirm that these values contain only printable ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your legend set with a custom size, which means it's being stretched to that size, regardless of the number of items in it. Try changing the `CustomPosition -> Height` value, or turning off the `CustomPosition` entirely and just placing the legend in the more usual way by dragging it around the chart.

Comment: When changing this to off it cuts off some of the legend values, Is there a way to have it grow automatically then?

Comment: If you know how many entries the legend will have, I suppose you could set a static height in `CustomPosition->Height` and a width as wide as the entire chart to minimise the chances of any truncation.

Comment: O never mind... Set MaxAutoSize = 100. Thank you for your help!